# Close windows explorer popup using Javascript function in Java code

Tags: java, javascript

How to close windows explorer popup using Javascript function in Java code?

I have to close windows explorer popup in my java code. I am using javascript function `window.close()` to close it as this window popup is breaking my loop.

Here is that piece of code:

```
  ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();  
  ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); 
  String script = "function winClose() {"+"var close_result =  window.parent.close();"+"" +"document.getElementById('close_result').value =   close_result;"+"console.log(\"change the box value\");}";  
  engine.eval(script);  
  Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;  
  inv.invokeFunction("winClose", "Window close!!" );
```

But it is giving me exception that `window` is not defined.

Actually I have never used Javascript in Java code. So please help me out with window close function in Javascript.

Comment: *"Thanks in advance

Megha"*  Don't include sigs. in questions, they are 4 lines of noise.

Comment: Forget the `ScriptEngine.  It won't work for this.  To work, the Javascript needs to be in the web page.  That in turn means the only (Java based) thing that can call it is an applet.

Comment: No..actually i am using selenium webdriver..for automating upload of files...those files are being read from a folder then are stored in a list array...according to size of listarray in loop..one by one files are being uploaded..but when one file is uploaded it is not going to next file upload because of windows explorer popup open...

Comment: It is purely java code which i am running from java project in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not mentioned this I hope your java code is a part of applet. In this case you should use live connect API instead of `ScriptingEngineManager`.

`ScriptingEngineManager` just runs Rhibno - pure java implementation of JavaScript language. You can use it either in applet (running in browser) or not. The engine you are running this way is absolutely independent on the javascript running into the browser and therefore does not know any objects injected by browser into its context like `window` or `document`.

Please take a look on [live connect](https://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/) documentation and examples for more details. Shortly it is originally developed by Netscape technology that allows applets to communicate with page where they are running. Therefore the package contains name of this company.

But please be careful: applets were obsolete almost 10 years ago and are well-known died technology these days. May I advise you to double check whether you indeed want to use it? There are thin client alternatives - check them.

Comment: *"applets were obsolete almost 10 years"*  Somebody should have informed Sun when they introduced extra parameters in Java 5 & support to be launched by JNLP (while still embedded) in Java 6.  Refer to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for a reasoned argument of why they should not be taught in CS 101, but they are *definitely not considered 'obsolete' by the maker.*